# QFile -- not reopening in text editor

Tags: c++, qt

There are two slots for open & close in my gui.
When i open a file its content are shown in text editor, then i press close button changes are save to file.

But Now when i again press, open & reload the same file. Nothing is shown in text editor, blank editor.

Why file is not reloading ?

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QFile file;
    QTextStream out;        
    QString url; // the url of the file



void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString openfileurl = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
    if(openfileurl.isEmpty() || openfileurl == url) return;

    file.setFileName(openfileurl);

    //if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text))
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite|QIODevice::Text))
    {
        url = openfileurl;
        ui->textEdit->setPlainText(QString::fromUtf8(file.readAll()));
    }

    //Set file to -- Qtextstream
    out.setDevice(&file);

}

void MainWindow::on_actionClose_triggered()
{
    //Set file to -- Qtextstream
    out << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

    file.close();
    ui->textEdit->clear();

}
```

Comment: One question. You're using RAW data when reading from file, and QTextStream when writing to it. You should use text stream to read and write or don't use it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
void MainWindow::on_actionClose_triggered()
{
    //Set file to -- Qtextstream
    out << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

    file.close();
    ui->textEdit->clear();
    uri.clear();
}
```

I think you should clear **uri** before make this check:
 `if(openfileurl.isEmpty() || openfileurl == url) return;`

It will blowup when `openfileurl == url`. And it will do it definitely sure if you didn't cleared the **uri**. And here you are:

> reload the same file

...with the same content... so, the if statement goes **true** and **returns**  that's why the code below is not executing the second time.